# Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin Forms PCL - can't install NodaTime 2.0 with NuGet

Tags: xamarin.forms, nodatime, visual-studio-mac

I'd like to use NodaTime with Xamarin Forms in a PCL, however the NuGet install fails with this message:

*Could not install package 'NodaTime 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.*

The NuGet package information says it doesn't have any dependencies, what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodaTime 2.0.0 only supports .NET45 or .NET Standard. You either need to update your Xamarin Forms project to .NET Standard, or downgrade your NodaTime version 1.3.4.